# Inserindo dados no DataGrid com falha para ID exclusivo não encontrado React Material-UI

Tags: javascript, react, datagrid, material-ui

o erro que me apresenta:
Error: Material-UI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property.
A row was provided without id in the rows prop:
{}
Eu faço a construção da minha tabela de acordo com os dados que eu adquiro de uma API.
Aqui está a minha tabela:

```
for(var i = 0; response.data.length > i ; i++)
{   
 field = Object.keys(response.data[i]) 
 headerName = Object.keys(response.data[i])
} 
for(var i = 0; field.length > i; i++)
{
  colunas.push({field:field[i],headerName:headerName[i],width:150}) 
}
for (var i = 0; response.data.length > i; i++){
  linha.push(response.data[i])
}
```

exemplo de retorno da coluna:

```
{field: "IdChamada", headerName: "IdChamada", widht: 150}
{field: "Campanha", headerName: "Campanha", widht: 150}
{field: "Tabulacao", headerName: "Tabulacao", widht: 150}
```

exemplo de retorno da linha:

```
 {IdChamada: 5035737, Campanha: Empresa_Update, Tabulacao: Concluido}
```

Meu DataGrid:

```
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
       <DataGrid 
        rows={rows} 
        columns={columns} 
        pageSize={10}  
        checkboxSelection
        id = "IdChamada"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o erro mostrado, uma ou mais linhas estão sem o atributo `id`.

A estrutura deve ser algo assim:

{ **id: 1**, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 }.

Suponho que o `linha.push(response.data[i])` seja aonde você "monta" o `rows`.
Se o data não contem o ID, você pode inserir um assim:  `linha.push({id: 1, ...response.data[i]})`

Lembrando que o ID deve ser único.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado :)

Comment: foi um prazer :)